# How can Multiple Andreev Reflections be explained as a succession of individual Andreev reflections?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

I have understood the mechanisms at work in single Andreev reflections (N(ormal)-S(uperconducter) interface) and Andreev bound states (N-S-N). For multiple Andreev reflections of order 3, the following mechanism makes sense to me:

[image: 3d order MAR]

But applying this reasoning to higher order processes such as this 5th order reflection doesn't seem to work

[image: 5th order MAR]

I can't explain the phenomena with successive Andreev reflections.. What have I not taken into account in my reasoning? Is it even possible to explain higher order Andreev reflections in this way?

Comment: This question is unclear. Which phenomena would you like to explain ? You use three different words : higher order / successive / multiple Andreev reflexion, and none is defined. I think it partly explains the confusion here. Multiple Andreev reflection (MAR) have been introduced by Tinkham, Blonder and Klapwijk in order to describe sub-gap structure of the I-V characteristics, see http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.27.6739 What you call successive Andreev reflexion is used to describe the Andreev modes in Josephson junctions (see e.g. the book by Nazarov and Blanter on quantum transport).

Comment: I forget to mention: one of the crucial ingredient of MAR is of course the voltage eV acquired by the particle once travelling across the interface. Since your question is unclear on this point, maybe this is the basic ingredient you forgot.

Comment: I was trying to explain MAR in NSN structures, not Josephson junctions. I was told that successive Andreev reflections (as shown in the top right figure I posted) were responsible for MAR. From what you say this information is wrong. This aspect being clarified, I shall explore the literature further, and eventually return here to explain it or to ask other questions. Thank you for your time.